# Disable parent page when popup window is open

Tags: asp.net

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but I really need to ask as I think mine maybe a bit special. So I open my popup through a hamburger menu that is coded under the master page(I am using web forms master page so that why the need of master page). What usually happens is that after the user login, it will show the main page and when he/she navigates to the menu to open the popup window, the back of popup window is the main page. Now I know that I should be disabling the main page, but then the on click event is inside the master page. How do I link both of them together?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “popup”? How are you opening it?

Comment: opening from a hamburger menu through javascript. the ususl window.open

Comment: I would say that my popup is like opening another page, but the size of the page is different

Answer (score -1):

If you use the background Div by hide / show with jquery, the background will be unclickable as this will happen on the top layer.

```
.side-menu {
   z-index: 100;
}

.background-black{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

Comment: this css code i should put it in the popup window?

Comment: Put in the main window with javascript code before the open popup window. (Popup window should be opened with javascript code)